# eclipse/RAD/CVSNT Team update error

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I'm getting the following error when performing Team-> Update from eclipse/RAD.  Any idea how I can resolve this?

```
cvs update -l -d -P "/Boss/ejbModule/com/arch/boss/dao/BossDeviceDAO.java" "/Boss/ejbModule/com/arch/boss/dao/BossDeviceDAO.java"
    U ejbModule/com/arch/boss/dao/BossDeviceDAO.java
    cvs server: nonmergeable file needs merge
    cvs server: revision 1.17 from repository is now in ejbModule/com/arch/boss/dao/BossDeviceDAO.java
    cvs server: file from working directory is now in .#BossDeviceDAO.java.1.16
    C ejbModule/com/arch/boss/dao/BossDeviceDAO.java
ok (took 0:21.461)
Error: The following warnings were reported while performing the "cvs update" command.
   Error: Boss: An unmergable conflict has occurred for binary file /Boss/ejbModule/com/arch/boss/dao/BossDeviceDAO.java. Revision 1.17 has been loaded and overwritten local changes have been saved in file /Boss/ejbModule/com/arch/boss/dao/.#BossDeviceDAO.java.1.16
***
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the CVS folder, the Entries file contains the entry for the file that I tried to update with version of 1.6.  But in CVS repository, the latest version is 1.7.  I did a compare of the source on my local and version 1.7 in the repository and see that I have the latest.  So, I use notepad and manually update the entry to version 1.7 and the problem went away.